# How to get ChoiceField data based on current user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model StaffProfile.while creating a form  for `Visit`i want to get staff_user data(Based on current user) to that ChoiceField (`to_meet`).

`models.py`

```
class StaffProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      related_name="user_profile")
      staff_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True, 
      related_name="staff_user")

class Visit(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200, name="name")
     gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICE, max_length=1, name="gender")
     mobile = models.CharField(max_length=18, default="", name="mobile")
     to_meet = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`forms.py`

```
class VisitForm(forms.ModelForm):
   to_meet = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], required=False, label="Select Staff")
   class Meta:
     model = Visit
     fields = ("__all__")

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(VisitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['to_meet'].choices = StaffProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list("staff_user")
```

Comment: where is your views?

Comment: view is just to render the form.i updated a form  overide method.but problem is i cant acess current user so am geting error. `name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: Can you show that view? Because it also takes a small role here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially override the **`__init__()`** method of your view

```
class VisitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(VisitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['to_meet'].choices = [self.request.user]

    to_meet = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], required=False, label="Select Staff")

    class Meta:
        model = Visit
        fields = "__all__"  # small typo here
```

Then, in your view,

```
def foo_view(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = VisitForm(request.POST,request=request)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # do somrthing
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the request from view to form. For example:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = VisitForm(request=request)
    # rest of the code
```

and use it in the form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  request = kwargs.pop('request')
  super(VisitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  self.fields['to_meet'].choices = StaffProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list("staff_user")
```